# My eyes look at the oposite direction. Why?

Tags: javascript, css

I was following a youtube tutorial on how to make animated eyes that follow the mouse but my eyes look in the opposite direction.

I got stuck at first because I forgot to write script type="text/javascript". After that, I manage to finish the code but my eyes look in the opposite direction of my mouse. It must be mathematical but this is the first time that I do something on JS and I can't find it out.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove', eyeball);
        function eyeball() {
            const eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
            eye.forEach (function(eye){
            let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2);
            let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2);
            let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
            let rotation = (radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 270;
            eye.style.transform = "rotate("+rotation+"deg)"
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: For what it's worth you don't need the "type" attribute, `<script>` is good enough.

Comment: Where are your eyes facing initially? It would help us if you could put a runnable snippet into you question.